# Excel VBA: Macro not Initializing Strings for Cell Value, not Accepting Site Connection

Tags: excel, string, vba, loops, connection

I am trying to write a loop macro to Excel VBA that takes a flight path from a cell in Sheet 1 (starting at row 1993), inserts the path into a website that calculates the flight data (Great Circle Mapper, shown here: http://www.gcmap.com/), pulls the data from a table on the website into Sheet 2 (starting at row 1996), deletes excess data, and removes "mi" from the miles flown (to leave a numerical value).

My first problem seems to begin with the start of the macro.

While I have defined the counter variable, the cell value variable, and the URL string variable (to concatenate with the cell value variable), debugging shows that only the counter variable gets properly initialized. The cell value variable ("Flight" which is supposed to start at row 1993, column O) does not get initialized, which then causes the URL and name variables not to run properly. Shown here:

```
ToInfinity = 1993
Flight = Cells(ToInfinity, 15).Value
url = "URL;http://www.gcmap.com/dist?P=" & Flight
name = "dist?P=" & Flight
```

As for my second problem, on the few times the macro has initialized each variable, the connection argument shown here:

```
("With ActiveSheet.QueryTables.Add(Connection:= _
    url, Flight:=Range("$A$1996:$G$1996"))
```

Gives me a runtime error, and this block of code is highlighted by the debugger.

The entirety of my code is shown below:

```
Sub PULLFROMGCM()
'
' PULLFROMGCM Macro
' Pulls data from great circle mapper
'
' Keyboard Shortcut: Ctrl+Shift+T
'
Dim Flight As String 
'String variable for each flight path to be analyzed by the website, "Great Circle Mapper"
'
Dim url As String
Dim ToInfinity As Long
' Counter variable for loop, beginning at row 1993 on sheet 1'
Dim name As String
Dim Milesflown As String
ToInfinity = 1993
Flight = Cells(ToInfinity, 15).Value
url = "URL;http://www.gcmap.com/dist?P=" & Flight
name = "dist?P=" & Flight
Do While Not IsEmpty(Cells(ToInfinity, 15))



Sheets("Sheet2").Select
    With ActiveSheet.QueryTables.Add(Connection:= _
        url, Flight:=Range("$A$1996:$G$1996"))
        .CommandType = 0
        .name = name
        .FieldNames = True
    .RowNumbers = False
    .FillAdjacentFormulas = False
    .PreserveFormatting = True
    .RefreshOnFileOpen = False
    .BackgroundQuery = True
    .RefreshStyle = xlInsertDeleteCells
    .SavePassword = False
    .SaveData = True
    .AdjustColumnWidth = True
    .RefreshPeriod = 0
    .WebSelectionType = xlSpecifiedTables
    .WebFormatting = xlWebFormattingNone
    .WebTables = """mdist"""
    .WebPreFormattedTextToColumns = True
    .WebConsecutiveDelimitersAsOne = True
    .WebSingleBlockTextImport = False
    .WebDisableDateRecognition = False
    .WebDisableRedirections = False
    .Refresh BackgroundQuery:=False
End With
Milesflown = "G:2001"
ActiveCell.Range("A1996:G2000").Select
Selection.QueryTable.Delete
Selection.ClearContents
Sheets("Sheet1").Select

If InStr(Milesflown, "mi") <> 0 Then
Cells(ToInfinity, 11).Value = Left(Milesflown, " ")
End If
ToInfinity = ToInfinity + 1
Loop
End Sub
```

[Link to Excel file from Google Drive](https://drive.google.com/file/d/0BxR5TrrROtV_ZGFEVlhLaXFkcEU/view)

Comment: Can you post a link to your excel file, or it's screenshot? That would help in debugging your code..

Comment: I don't know how. What would be the option in StackOverflow to upload a file?

Comment: Mmm.. you could upload your file to (DropBox|Google Drive|One Drive...) and post a link here?

Comment: It should show up now, under the final block of code. Some parts of the first sheet are messy, due to trouble with subtotals, but the only column I'm concerned with right now in the first sheet is column O.

Comment: It's showing "request access", that is, people don't have access to your file unless you give them permission to access it. I've requested access to your file and you should receive an email for it.

Comment: It should now be set to "view" for you

Comment: Thanks.. I'm looking into it.

Comment: I have many questions regarding your code. First, why have you hard coded values such as `$A$1996:$G$1996` ?

Comment: One thing that I found amiss in your code was `QueryTables.Add(Connection:= url, Flight:=Range` should be `QueryTables.Add(Connection:=url, Destination:=Range`, because there is no parameter named "Flight" for the query table add method.

Answer (score 0):

The obvious mistake in your code is that you are not updating the `Flight`, `url` and `name` variables inside your loop.

Correcting the above mistakes, and a few syntax errors (like using ActiveCell instead of ActiveSheet), the following code does what you want.

```
Sub PULLFROMGCM()
'
' PULLFROMGCM Macro
' Pulls data from great circle mapper
'
' Keyboard Shortcut: Ctrl+Shift+T
'
Dim Flight As String
Dim url As String
Dim ToInfinity As Long
Dim name As String
Dim Milesflown As String
ToInfinity = 1993


Do While Not IsEmpty(Cells(ToInfinity, 15))

' Update the variables in your loop as well
Flight = Cells(ToInfinity, 15).Value
url = "URL;http://www.gcmap.com/dist?P=" & Flight
name = "dist?P=" & Flight

' Calculate how far sheet 2 has rows
Sheets("Sheet2").Select
HowFar = Application.WorksheetFunction.CountA(Range("A:A")) + 3

    With ActiveSheet.QueryTables.Add(Connection:= _
        url, Destination:=Range("A" & (HowFar + 1) & ":G" & (HowFar + 1)))
        .name = name
        .FieldNames = True
        .RowNumbers = False
        .FillAdjacentFormulas = False
        .PreserveFormatting = True
        .RefreshOnFileOpen = False
        .BackgroundQuery = True
        .RefreshStyle = xlInsertDeleteCells
        .SavePassword = False
        .SaveData = True
        .AdjustColumnWidth = True
        .RefreshPeriod = 0
        .WebSelectionType = xlSpecifiedTables
        .WebFormatting = xlWebFormattingNone
        .WebTables = """mdist"""
        .WebPreFormattedTextToColumns = True
        .WebConsecutiveDelimitersAsOne = True
        .WebSingleBlockTextImport = False
        .WebDisableDateRecognition = False
        .WebDisableRedirections = False
        .Refresh BackgroundQuery:=False
    End With
    Milesflown = Range("G" & (HowFar + 6)).Value
    ActiveSheet.Range("A" & (HowFar + 1) & ":G" & (HowFar + 5)).Select
    Selection.QueryTable.Delete
    Selection.ClearContents
    Sheets("Sheet1").Select

If InStr(Milesflown, "mi") <> 0 Then
    Milesflown = Replace(Milesflown, "mi", "")
    Cells(ToInfinity, 12).Value = Milesflown
End If

MsgBox (Milesflown)
    ToInfinity = ToInfinity + 1

Loop
End Sub
```

Comment: I see now. Thank you very much for looking over my code. I noticed later on, as well, that I should start the macro by selecting Sheet 1. The Flight variable didn't initialize when I started off with Sheet 2 active.

Comment: @EdC: From a performance point of view, activating/selecting sheets is a drag. Instead you should reference the sheet objects and get their ranges from their references. For example, `Sheets('Sheet1').Range("A1").Value` will give you the first cell's value. Also if you feel the answer was helpful enough and answered your problem, can you please accept it (:))?